# Usage of Typescript's "specifies" with Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

In my project I use Cloud Functions written in `"typescript": "^4.6.4"` in which I've was about to start using `satisfies` feature of language but it fails to compile (weirdly enough the vscode intellisense don't mind it at all.

Is the feature supported by Cloud Functions?

package.json:

```
"engines": { "node": "18" }, 
"devDependencies": { "typescript": "^4.6.4" },
"dependencies": {
  "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
  "firebase-functions": "^4.2.1",
// ...
```

tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "baseUrl": ".",
// ...
```

I have an `error TS1005: ',' expected.` upon trying to write into  Firestore document. Changing `satisfies` to `as` fixes the issue, but I suppose it should work either way.

```
  docRef.set({
    obj1: 0xbad,
    obj2: 0xb0b,
  } satisfies Obj1Obj2Type);
```

Comment: Your question should show the code and configuration that doesn't work the way you expect, including instructions to reproduce the issue. Cloud Functions doesn't directly support TypeScript at all (it supports TS compiled into JS), so something is wrong with the way you are building your project. It's not a matter of CF supporting some TS language feature.  I suggest starting with a project that does work, then explaining also exactly what you added to it that causes it to fail, and the failure message.

Comment: Which line of code is the error message referring to? The full error message should tell you.  Please copy the full error message into the question, in addition to the surrounding execution context of the code (like the whole enclosing function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `satisfies` keyword was added in TypeScript in version 4.9.  See the documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html

The latest version is 5.0.4, so try upgrading to that if you want all of the latest that TypeScript offers as of today.

```
npm install -D typescript@latest
```

Comment: Thanks Doug for your input. One more question, is it advisable to use latest Typescript's features with Firebase Cloud Functions or is there some recommendation regarding TS version in conjunction with FCF?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  TypeScript compiles down to plain JavaScript in any case, no matter what language features you use, targeting whatever version of JS you specify in your TS config.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions run *JavaScript*, not TypeScript, because [TypeScript is transpiled to JavaScript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-type-erasure-in-typescript/).

As a result there is no consideration to be made about what TypeScript features work or do not work in Cloud Functions -- the [Functions Framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/) has *no concept of TypeScript at all in a running function* because every function that runs must be pure JavaScript, whether it was written that way originally or was created by `tsc` before being deployed.

If you are unable to compile your TypeScript code to JavaScript then you have a problem with your TypeScript code or configuration and that has nothing to do with Cloud Functions or the Functions Framework.

Comment: While all this may be correct, it's not really helpful in solving the problem.  The OP needs to explain their setup in order to identify what the actual problem is.  Just saying "the problem isn't with Cloud Functions" doesn't advance the solution.

Comment: @DougStevenson Their actual question was *Is the feature supported by Cloud Functions?* and I answered that question. I agree that it doesn't resolve the problem that they described in their post but they specifically did not ask about how to resolve that problem nor did they provide enough context to resolve that problem. I answered the question they asked, which should prompt them to ask a different question about the specific problem they're experiencing.

Comment: I'm saying they're asking the wrong question, which happens a lot on Stack Overflow.  It's an [X/Y question](https://xyproblem.info/), which is really not good for Stack Overflow, doesn't help the asker, and really need to be re-asked so it can help others in the future who exhibit the same problem.  The question was re-asked, so maybe take another look?

Comment: I understand your point. I think that XY problems are fine to have on StackOverflow because there are others who will have the same misunderstanding and seek out questions like this one. My answer clears up that misunderstanding. It's up to OP to then create a new question based on the knowledge they've gained because they're the only ones that can ask an appropriate question. I don't think an answer that explains that `satisfies` is in TS 4.9 answers the question *Is the feature supported by Cloud Functions?* because it has nothing to do with Cloud Functions. It's purely about TypeScript.

Comment: I think this is one of those areas where people can disagree without either one being right or wrong and I appreciate you rooting out the TS 4.9 answer for OP.

Comment: Never once said you were wrong. In fact, I pointed out that you were right.  Just making suggestions on how to be more helpful, which is the core of what we do here on SO.

Comment: Correct, you never said I was wrong and I apologize if it sounded like I was saying that. I agree completely with your sentiment and I think this kind of back-and-forth is emblematic of making a better SO. Thank you.